# What effects does 'Post Processing' in the 'Visual > Custom Render settings' do?

Tags: pc, dead-space-2

Since Post Processing is pretty much a catch-all term for different kinds of visual or graphics effects, I'm wondering if I should disable it or not, depending on its effects specific to Dead Space 2.

I especially would like to know if it does post process-AA (like FXAA), as I am already forcing 8x MSAA on Dead Space 2 in my graphics card's driver.

[image: Dead Space 2 custom render settings screenshot 1]
[image: Dead Space 2 custom render settings screenshot 1]
[image: Dead Space 2 custom render settings screenshot 1]

Comment: This is actually really interesting, because at least I'd put all those "custom render settings" under a category "post processing" rather than creating a separate point. I don't have the game, so will leave this to others to answer, but "post processing" usually refers to things Happening to the whole scene, like anti-aliasing, film grain, color adjustments, etc.

Comment: As Mario said; almost everything else on that list is also a post-process effect. So it's likely to be some unnamed extra effect that they came up with that improves the look or mood of the game in some way. If I had the game myself I'd take screen-shots with it on and off and compare. You could do this yourself since actually seeing the difference will be far more meaningful than reading a description of what it's meant to do. If you can't see a difference then leave it off since post-process effects consume system resources.

Comment: @Mario I thought so too. Post Processing is pretty much a catch-all term for different kinds of effects. This is why I asked it here, in case someone already knows what the effects are specific to Dead Space 2. I'm specially curious of it also does post-process AA (like FXAA) as I am already forcing 8x MSAA in my graphics card's driver.

Comment: @Ian My concern is more about what the Post Processing effects are (especially if it does post-process AA), and less of its performance hit. "*You could do this yourself...*" I posted here, in case someone already knows. =) I tried turning Post Processing on and off a few times in the first part of the game but haven't been able to notice any effects. I might have to try again.

Comment: [This is for Dead Space 1](http://www.bit-tech.net/gaming/pc/2008/10/21/dead-space/4), but its probably a similar effect.  You'll see at the bottom it seems to change the color hue slightly in the screenshot.  Other than that, no noticeable differences seem to be present.